# Are there 3D tilings of a 3D projective hyperplane or 3-sphere?

Tags: geometry, 3d, spherical-geometry, polyhedra, tiling

I noticed that pentagons tile the projective plane (a [spherical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_polyhedron) [dodecahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron)).  Something they do not do on a flat euclidean plane.

*Is there analogous 3D tilings ([honeycombs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeycomb_%28geometry%29)) of a [3D projective hyperplane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Projective_planes_in_higher_dimensional_projective_spaces) or 4D sphere ([3-sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-sphere))?*

To put it a different way, the cube, octahedra, and tetrahedra are the only regular solid that fills 3D space. Does this situation change when we are working in a curved space?

Comment: Perhaps look up 120-cell and 600-cell and see if those are what you want.  Curved 2D space is 3D space, but it appears as 2D locally for the case of the spherical dodecahedron.

Comment: We know that *n*-sphere is a Riemannian manifold, i.e. has angles and lengths. How do you define “regular” shapes in *projective* spaces, indeed? Are you sure that distinguish projective and elliptic geometries well?